# How to execute framework-dependent deployment using dotnet publish with remote host

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, msbuild, .net-core

We have a continuous build going on and are trying to publish a dotnet core app as a windows service. We can do this using visual studio with the following publish profile

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <ProjectGuid>d655df5a-9266-470d-becd-6d62c919e961</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <_IsPortable>true</_IsPortable>
    <publishUrl>C:\publish\webapi</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

At first we tried the path of least resistance and tried to call
`dotnet publish project /p:PublishProfile=<FolderProfileName>`

This command ignored the publish profile settings so we fell back on manually setting the properties. This however, would only build either a self-contained app with an exe but all the net core dlls or a framework dependent app with just dlls

Command executed

```
dotnet publish Project.csproj -c "Release" -o "C:\Publish\App" -r "win-x64" --self-contained false
```

Question is how can I mimic the VS2017 Publish of net core apps using the publish profile since I hit the problems I specified above.

Target output would be to publish the net core app without the aspnetcore dlls but with a remote host executable.

Comment: ...and the question is...?

Comment: Updated title and description. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The publish profile is meant to be used along with the build, by passing

```
-p:DeployOnBuild=true -p:PublishProfile=<ProfileName>
```

to `dotnet build` or `msbuild`. This is the same as "classic" ASP.NET projects.

If you only need filesystem deployments, you can use `dotnet publish` instead which can directly create publish outputs to target locations (web deploy uses the same mechanisms internally by publishing to a temporary location and then copying, zipping etc.).

`dotnet publish` will create a self-contained deployment automatically when passed a runtime identifier (`-r` option).

If you also want a host exe to boot up the runtime, you can also use

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 --self-contained false -p:UseAppHost=true
```

to emit a .exe file that you can use as windows service instead of `path\to\dotnet.exe path\to\app.dll`, which will still use the machine-wide .NET Core install. This may or may not become part of the default output in 3.0.

Comment: Thank you Martin, this was very detailed and easy to understand and follow. However, when I set up a service pointing to the exe generated by the publish, the service doesn't start and does not write any logs in the event viewer or the custom logger

Comment: Are there any documentation regarding the properties we can pass into dotnet publish/build? I don't seem to see a complete list

Comment: I tried out your first suggestion with the -DeployOnBuild and it worked perfectly. Thank you!